# Tips/Advice for Stringing a lacrosse stick with a "V" Shooter Pocket and 2 Cross strings

Tags: equipment, lacrosse

I am a lacrosse player who primarily plays attack. I am starting to string my own heads, and I was looking for any tips. My team's *equipment expert* could not offer me much assistance, much to my dismay. I have been to Total Lacrosse for all my mesh and some tips. I am looking for a way to get better whip on my shots, and i am told a V pocket will give me that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May I have an explanation on why this question is being categorized as "**general health and medical advice**?"

Comment: To the OP, Welcome to Sports SE! Thank you for introducing the sport of lacrosse here!

Comment: See [How to Properly String your Lacrosse Head](http://laxworld.com/lacrosse-blog/2013/11/howto-properly-string-your-lacrosse-head).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To string a V pocket is pretty simple. All you need to do is thread the shooting string above your pocket in a V or U shape. This will give your stick more ball control. To get more whip you need to tighten your shooting strings.